# Right course of action for answers with deleted content

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, specific-answer

I encountered an answer on Stack Overflow that is just something along the lines of:

> This answer is no longer relevant due to edits in the original question

and nothing else. I thought this was weird, so I looked at the edit history and saw that the original answer was not only still relevant (in my opinion), but contained useful info that I was looking for at that moment.

So I went ahead and suggested an edit that still had the original answer but also had a line at the end saying the above comment. The edit was rejected. Who is correct in this situation?

Here is the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62306969/4021308

I mean no ill to the answerer at all, just genuinely curious about what SO believes about this.

Comment: Huh. OP accepted it, so I guess they found it useful. Then the answerer edited out the answer later. Probably we should just roll it back? If the answerer wants the content removed since they think it doesn't fit the problem anymore, they can mod-flag to delete it (they can't delete it themselves because it's accepted)

Comment: @CertainPerformance I don't think the acceptance means anything on there. Possibly the answerer was getting annoyed with the so-called [chameleon question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) since the question was edited with more debugging problem.

Comment: @CertainPerformance [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62303412/defining-multiple-ec2-instances-in-terraform-using-count-and-registering-them-wi/62306969#comment110221598_62306969) contradicts it. Although it depends on when the asker chose to accept the answer...

Comment: Chameleon question indeed ...  I deleted all my comments so it's hard to see what happened unless you can see deleted comments ... but the answer from @BoltClock below gets it right

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Moderators will honor an answerer's request to delete their accepted answer if it's deemed no longer useful. An answerer can make this request by flagging their answer for moderator attention. If an answer is still overwhelmingly useful and the answerer still wants nothing more to do with it we may have the staff disassociate it from their account instead.

In this case, since the answerer has made clear their intention to remove their answer, and the asker has already said that it doesn't solve their problem, not to mention being unkind with their comment (I believe this is in direct response to a comment the answerer has since removed, which wasn't a personal attack to begin with, but a constructive criticism of the question), I've left a comment prompting the asker about this thread and letting them know I'll remove their answer if they just say the word. I've also rolled back the edit. I don't know if the asker knows they can unaccept answers, so for now I'm not going to accuse them of maliciously keeping the answer accepted...

Comment: This makes sense. I actually didn't notice the comments under the answer; the asker was definitely hostile for some reason, which explains the (attempted) deletion

Comment: @cigien: At least you kept the string "kind"!

Comment: I try to keep my edits as minimal as possible ;) I hope the edit was ok, I'm a little bit of a stickler when it comes to language like that.

Comment: @cigien: I still have a little bit of "angry moderator" left in me, but it's fine either way.

Comment: FWIW, it seems that part of the problem here is that the author of the question _changed the question_ after it had been answered. Which as far as I know, is a decided "no-no" on this site. Perhaps the best path to rectifying the situation is to rollback the question to the version for which the answer makes sense, and have the question's author post the new question as, well...a new question.

Comment: Since that is my answer, let me add my 2cents ... @BoltClock you are right, in a now deleted comment I provided feedback and the answer was an unkind comment suggesting I'm "merely going after stackoverflow rankings" ... my rule is not to engage & best course of action is to delete everything that associates me with that post